# HSV shows black as green

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

I am trying to detect a (what I assume) black line.
However when I look at the HSV image it shows me that the line is green.
When I make the image black or white, the line can't distinguish itself from the white background.

[image: Here is the image]

How come the black line is showing up as green when I convert to HSV? and if so, what colour range is green in HSV?

This is how I filter black as of now:

```
            hsv = cv.cvtColor(self.frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            self.frame = hsv
            # define range of black color in HSV

            lower_val = np.array([0,0,0])

            upper_val = np.array([179,100,130])


            # Threshold the HSV image to get only black colors
            mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)

            res = cv.bitwise_and(self.frame,self.frame, mask= mask)

            # invert the mask to get black letters on white background

            res2 = cv.bitwise_not(mask)

            # display image

            cv.imshow("img", res)

            cv.imshow("img2", res2)
```

Comment: Why did you choose that array for `upper_val`?

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible?

Comment: @SarahMesser You can neglect the bitwise operations. The only thing relevant here is the HSV. The reason I chose for the upper_val array values was because I came across an example which used that.

Comment: @Kitswas Not really. I can (at best) take a photo of the stairs and upload it so you can use it as an image, but that's it.

Comment: imshow interprets the image as BGR. So you see green because you have the second channel (S) high and the first (H) and third (V) ones low. It's easier to segment black color in BGR (all channels near 0).

Comment: Black in HSV would be something like lower(0,0,0) and upper(255,255,lowValue) or upper(255,lowValue1, lowValue2) depending on whether you want a dark color to be black or only dark-gray to be black as well.

Comment: @Micka Why would the white stairs with the black line BOTH be white or black then ? How come it cannot distinguish them ?

Comment: Currently you are using low to middle saturation and low to middle intensity, which includes a not too bright "white" and black.

Comment: @Micka and therefore it considers black on white and white on black as one color? so the upper should be (as you mentioned) 255,255,someLowerValue in order to filter out the black from the white ?

Comment: Black is low intensity (V channel), no matter what the other channels are. A very dark red is black, a very dark green is black, etc. Even a very dark white is black. Hue channel is the color, but the lower the saturation channel, the less colorful is that color, going down to gray. White is a bright gray, so it has a low saturation and a high intensity channel.